# Visual Studio solution with g-tests on AppVeyor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, continuous-integration, googletest, appveyor

I have project-files, i have a test, i have a CMakeLists.txt.
I need to run test on AppVeyor. And I am a layman in VS.

My appveyor.yml

```
    version: '{build}'

    os: Visual Studio 2015
    configuration:
      - Release

    build_script:
      - mkdir build
      - cd build
  - cmake -Dgtest_build_samples=ON ..
  - msbuild gtest-demo.sln
```

My CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(gtest-demo)

enable_language(C)
enable_language(CXX)

if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES GNU)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         "-Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -Woverloaded-virtual -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG   "-O0 -g3")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
endif()

include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    )

add_library(
    example
    src/vec2.cpp
    src/obstacle.cpp
    src/map.cpp
    )

set(GOOGLETEST_ROOT googletests/googletest CACHE STRING "Google Test source root")

include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${GOOGLETEST_ROOT}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${GOOGLETEST_ROOT}/include
    )

set(GOOGLETEST_SOURCES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${GOOGLETEST_ROOT}/src/gtest-all.cc
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${GOOGLETEST_ROOT}/src/gtest_main.cc
    )


#########################################################

foreach(_source ${GOOGLETEST_SOURCES})
    set_source_files_properties(${_source} PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)
endforeach()
################################################3
add_library(googletest ${GOOGLETEST_SOURCES})

add_executable(
    unit_tests
    tests/main.cpp
    tests/test.cpp
    )

add_dependencies(unit_tests googletest)

target_link_libraries(
    unit_tests
    googletest
    example
    pthread
    )

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_test(unit ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/unit_tests)
```

And error-logs:

```
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\projects\gr-cl\googletests\googletest\src\gtest-all.cc': No such file or directory [C:\projects\gr-cl\build\googletest.vcxproj]
  c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\projects\gr-cl\googletests\googletest\src\gtest_main.cc': No such file or directory [C:\projects\gr-cl\build\googletest.vcxproj]
```

I can't understand, why? I added Include and stuff in "include directories". How to get the ball rolling?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is some error in path. Maybe some small typo and it should with like googletests/googletest**S** or something. Best way to check is to [RDP to build worker](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) and check what is real path.